# Remove an application from Notification Center

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, nsusernotification

I was playing around with making a small cocoa application and using the new Notification Center API in Mountain Lion.

However my app is now present in the notification center settings, together with Calendar, Messages and so on.

As it was just me playing around, I want it to disappear from the list now, but I cannot find anyway to remove it.

I tried several things, dragging it out, holding <kbd>alt</kbd> + *Right Click* and so on.

Where could the (probably a) *plist* that populates that list be located?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

While I don't believe purging applications from Notification Center that have once registered is a documented step, there's clearly some stuff setup to do that.

Here's what I found out:

This data isn't stored in a plist but rather a sqlite database.

If you look into `~/Library/Application Support/NotificationCenter/<id>`
(in my case, I only had one directory under NotificationCenter), you'll see an `<id>.db` file under the  directory.<sup>*</sup>

Poking inside, I see tables like `app_info`, `app_source`, `presented_notifications`, etc. Furthermore, the schema includes a clean-up trigger that looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER app_deleted AFTER DELETE ON app_info
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM scheduled_notifications     WHERE app_id=old.app_id;
    DELETE FROM presented_notifications     WHERE app_id=old.app_id;
    DELETE FROM presented_alerts            WHERE app_id=old.app_id;
    DELETE FROM notifications               WHERE app_id=old.app_id;
    DELETE FROM app_push                    WHERE app_id=old.app_id;
    DELETE FROM app_loc                     WHERE app_id=old.app_id;
    DELETE FROM app_source                  WHERE app_id=old.app_id;
END;
```

Using a sqlite3 client, if you do a

```sql
select * from app_info;
```

the first column is the `app_id` of your application, the second column is your app's bundleid. Find your application based on the bundleid. Then do a

```sql
delete from app_info where app_id = <app_id>
```

where `<app_id>` is the correct `app_id` you found using your select command above.

After doing this, everything stayed around in Notification Center (both the center and System Preferences). I had to logout and log back in to see the changes take effect, but luckily, my multiple test apps are now gone.

---

*:

- <sup>[Hofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472790/hofi) points out that **since macOS 10.10**, said SQLite database can be found in the directory returned by shell command: `$(getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR)com.apple.notificationcenter/db` named just `db`.</sup>
- <sup>[jbg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1174521/jbg) notes that as of macOS Monterey (12.x), the directory path is now: `$(getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR)com.apple.notificationcenter/db2`, and the `db` database's `app_info` table has been renamed to `app`.</sup>

Answer (score 16):

Highlight the app in the list and hit `fn`+`backspace` or `del`/`delete` if you have that on your keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

If you delete the application (might need to empty the trash as well) and log out and back in, it gets removed from the list.

Answer (score 5):

The following, perhaps heavy-handed approach seems to work for me when I get into this mess. It avoids changing AppID/etc. at least.

1. Quit XCode
2. `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`
3. `killall usernoted`
4. `killall NotificationCenter`
5. `rm ~/Library/Application Support/NotificationCenter/*`
6. Open System Preferences → Notifications (this seems to restart everything)

Reboot/log out is not required in this method.

Answer (score 5):

I had trouble with BetterTouchTool not disappearing from the Notification Center after uninstall. Unfortunately, the methods mentioned here didn't work for me but I figured it out eventually.

For anybody having trouble getting this to work under High Sierra:

1. In terminal, navigate to NotificationCenter folder:

   ```
   cd $(getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR)/com.apple.notificationcenter/
   ```
2. get path using pwd and copy to clipboard
   (should be something like /var/folders/c3/289nmdsd2cz68yd5p47k553w0000gn/0/com.apple.notificationcenter)

   ```
   pwd
   ```
3. In finder, go to folder (cmd+shift+g) and paste path
4. Find the folder containing the db file and drag the entire folder to the trash
   (I had only one folder named "db2")
5. Empty Trash! (This is very important, didn't work on my machine without it)
6. Log Out and In again

There might be a more elegant way but this worked for me.
Note that for some reason, the Database gets rebuilt with the application_id still present in the db-table (which is called `app` instead of `app_id` on High Sierra, btw), however the entry disappeared from the notification center.

Answer (score 2):

I simply renamed the file in the NotificationCenter folder, then rebooted.  A new file was created which was populated with just the default apps.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS Catalina, the path to the db can be found with `lsof -p $(ps aux | grep -m1 usernoted | awk '{ print $2 }')| awk '{ print $NF }' | grep 'db2/db$' | xargs dirname`

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in the project which you were playing around with user notifications in to call

```
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] removeAllDeliveredNotifications];
```

from your app delegate's method `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.  This will remove all user notifications from the user notification center.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily from Xcode.

Open `Organizer`, and select the `Projects` tab at the top.
You will see a list of all your applications on the left side. For any application you want to remove, select it from the left-hand menu and choose `Delete...` for the `Derived Data`.

This still retains any user settings in Notification Center, as well as the notifications themselves.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Finder
2. Search Macintosh HD under the tab "This Mac"
3. Click Applications
4. Press Shift + Command + G
5. Type in ~/library
6. Click Application Support
7. Click Notification Center
8. Drag the only file that's there to the Trash
9. Quit all on going apps
10. Empty Trash
11. Restart

The application has been removed from your Notifications Center permanently based on personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to remove a notification, but in my case it was for a website (9to5mac) to be exact.  I could SEE it in System Preferences | Notifications and set it to be disabled, but I continued to get notifications.  I finally figured it out.  For websites you have to go into Safari, then Safari Preferences | Websites, then Notifications, then find the website and either set it to Deny or just remove it altogether.  I removed 9to5mac here and once I did, it was gone from the general Notification Center as well, what a pita!  but at least there is a way.

Also from my searching I too opened the notification DB file with a sqlite browser and my web notification "app" was not to be found, so you have to delete/disable it in Safari instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had 3, I don't think they were apps but site notifications.

I had to clear history and extensions from safari and chrome; they were gone from the notification center.