# How do I cancel orphaned NSUserNotifications on OS X?

Tags: macos, notifications, nsusernotification

I was doing some development with NSUserNotification in an OS X Yosemite app. It's all working great now, but in the process of development, I somehow orphaned scheduled daily NSUserNotifications on my system. Now I get notifications all day long that are unconnected to my app: clicking "Show" does not launch or switch to the app. I can disable all notifications for the app, but then the *actual*, non-orphaned notifications stop appearing, too.

Is there some place on the system where I can find a list of scheduled notifications and delete all the orphans? Maybe a file to edit or a database to update?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11993145/) (clearly my Google-foo failed me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this question duplicates [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11993145/), where [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13274825/) solved the problem for me. All I had to do was to delete the app, clear the derived files, and restart. Going into Notification Center, I made sure that the app was no longer listed.

Once I reinstalled the app, its notifications worked fine, and all the other random ones were gone.