# Use AppleScript to change System Preferences > App Badges

Tags: macos, applescript, applescript-objc

I'm trying to use AppleScript to control System Preferences in the background. Specifically, I am trying to Enable / Disable "Badge app icons" for each app. There is no global way to enable / disable badge app icons in system preferences. This must be done per app.

Any idea how this might be done?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broad, but here are some pointers:

- While `System Preferences.app` *can* be controlled from an AppleScript, support is limited to *revealing* (opening) the application to a specific pane and anchor (tab).
- Your best bet is to modify the underlying SQLite 3 database in which the per-application notification preferences are maintained - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12121673/45375) will hopefully get you started.

  - macOS comes with the `sqlite3` CLI.
  - From what I understand, while AppleScript has - limited - support for accessing SQLite databases via the `Database Events` app, using `do shell script` to call the `sqlite3` utility [may be the better option](http://www.macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24744).
    (In fact, in a brief test I wasn't even able to *open* a database in AppleScript on my macOS 10.12.4 machine)