# Remove scheduled notifications on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, notifications, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

I used C#/Mono to schedule a notification with `NSUserNotificationCenter` like so:

```
var not = new NSUserNotification();
not.Title = ...;
not.DeliveryDate = ...;
not.DeliveryRepeatInterval = new NSDateComponents() {
  Second = 65
};
...
NSUserNotificationCenter.DefaultUserNotificationCenter
                        .ScheduleNotification(not);
```

This worked as intended. An initial notification appeared and then after a 65sec delay the next one and then the next one etc.

But: After I quit the application the notifications kept appearing! And they still do.

I deleted the application and emptied the trash can. I restarted my Mac. I switched notifications for the application on/off in *settings/notification center*. All to no avail.

I followed advice to delete SQLite notification databases down in the belly of OSX Sierra. There were only old *.db* files. Nothing changed.

Neither can I remove the application from the notification center, nor can I stop the scheduled notifications.

What else can I do?

PS: To be precise: I checked this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993145/remove-application-from-notification-center), but nothing from there worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem myself. The solution indeed was already present in the [previous posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993145/remove-application-from-notification-center). But I somehow did not apply it correctly. So here are the steps if you're stuck with unwanted notifications on OSX Sierra:

1. Find the notification center database: `cd (getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR)/com.apple.notificationcenter/db` (replace the `()` with backticks!)
2. Determine the full path with `pwd`, e.g. `/var/folders/b4/qw_sstpn1jqd8ypb1zgc7vww0000gn/0/com.apple.notificationcenter/db`. This references a directory, not a file yet!
3. Open the file called `db` in the directory found, e.g. `/var/folders/b4/qw_sstpn1jqd8ypb1zgc7vww0000gn/0/com.apple.notificationcenter/db/db` - yes, it's `db/db` at the end - with a SQLite editor.
4. Search for you app with `select * from app_info where bundleid = "%yourappname%". Remember the`app_id` value shown.
5. Delete the app info record and thereby any related data in other tables with `delete from app_info where app_id = <your app id>`.
6. Save the changes to the database if necessary.
7. Restart your Mac and log back in. You should be fine now.

I first was confused by my app still being listed in *settings/notifications*. But at least the annoying notifications don't appear anymore.

Good luck for you!

Comment: Thanks for this! I used your answer, as well as Oscar Zhang's answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64629/does-the-os-x-log-notifications-from-the-notification-center) to solve my issue by editing the db file in the db2 folder. I found the app_id in the app table and then deleted it (which causes the 'app_deleted' trigger to delete the app from all the other tables). This is for Mojave.